# TFS Update Status of Local Workspace Files

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I am using Visual Studio 2013 with TFS 2012.  We are just moving to TFS from another source control application (StarTeam).

Our projects are enormous, so after creating a new branch in StarTeam the users would simply copy their local folder of the most recent project and rename it to the new version.  This way we would not need to re-download the entire project.  StarTeam has an option to "Update Status" - it would see that the files already existed locally and update to note that you have the current version.

We cannot find a way to do this in TFS.  The status is always "Not downloaded."  Refresh doesn't do it.  I can run a Compare and it will report that all the files exist locally and there are no differences from the server version, but still it won't indicate that I have the latest version.

Are we just s**t out of luck?

Comment: Edited Feb. 4, 2015:  We use local workspaces and had this issue with the initial branches set up in TFS, which we had already downloaded from StarTeam.

However, now that we are creating branches off of those initial branches the system works mostly like it did in StarTeam - we are not forced to re-download the entire project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TFS workspace are server based, and right now TFS thinks you don't have the file downloaded that's why it's saying not downloaded.  If your workspace is either local or server based you'll still have to do an initial download to either get the baseline version to disk (local) or let the server know you have the files downloaded (server based).

ET

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in general I would say that re-downloading them is the easiest and most bulletproof way. If you are remote to the server, just deploy tfs proxy locally.
I would swear that Ed Hintz had blog post long time ago describing how to solve your problem, but I cannot find it. If you are really, really determined you can use UpdateLocalVersionQueue and update server with your local versions manually. However this may be very, very tricky and I would highly recommend going with the simplest solution.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb138603(v=vs.100).aspx